# Function not working creating a variable and using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function which changes the width of some images. This happens when I hover over a different div in a different function. For some reason the the called function only performs some lines of code and then it stops.

```
function hey()
{
    alert(0);
    var $imgContent = ('.imgContent');
    $imgContent.css("width","10%");
    alert(2);
}

var $content = $('.content');
$content.mouseenter(function() {

    $content.removeClass('full').addClass('partial');
    $(this).addClass('full').removeClass('partial');
    $(this).find('.img1').css('display','none');
    $(this).find('.img2').css('display','');

    if($(this).hasClass('cont1')){
        alert(1);
       hey();
    }

    if($(this).hasClass('cont2')){

    }

    if($(this).hasClass('cont3')){

    }

    if($(this).hasClass('cont4')){

    }
}).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.img1').css('display','');
        $(this).find('.img2').css('display','none');
        $(this).removeClass('full').addClass('partial');


    });
```

In the mouseenter() function when I check if `$(this).hasClass('cont1')` then I perform an alert, which works. After that I call on function hey(). This is where my problem arises. After calling function hey() i perform another alert(0) , which also works. But the lines of code after that do not get executed and the last alert(2) doesn't work either.

Comment: You should check out the console, it should point you in the right direction much of the time.

Comment: When you have an issue like this it is much easier to just check your console rather than insert a million alerts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your code.

Replace:

```
var $imgContent = ('.imgContent');
```

With

```
var $imgContent = $('.imgContent');
```

Comment: wow, a simple code error. Thanks a lot buddy, i was stuck on this for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your jquery object definition.

Per [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> jQuery() — which can also be written as $() — searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements

so in your case you should have:

```
var $imgContent = $('.imgContent');
$imgContent.css("width","10%");
```

Also, it's important to note that in your `.mouseenter()` function you refer to:

```
$content.removeClass('full').addClass('partial');
$(this).addClass('full').removeClass('partial');
```

$content and $(this) both refer to the same object, so in essence these lines are pointless.